# Query to show missing critical updates and security updates from 15days ago and longer

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I am trying to create a query that will show me the missing critical updates and security updates on VM but only from 15days ago and longer but not within 15days.
So I have created this query...

```
Update
| where Classification in ("Security Updates", "Critical Updates")
| where UpdateState == 'Needed' and Optional == false and Approved == true
| where TimeGenerated > ago(15d)
| summarize count() by Classification, Computer, _ResourceId
```

but when I run this query it gives me missing updates within 15 days, but what I am trying to achieve is missing updates from 15 days ago.

Any contribution will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you want updates data before 15 days, give `where TimeGenerated < ago(15d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Update events are reported many times per day. Youn need to filter the last report and check the PublishedDate.

```
Update
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where PublishedDate < ago(15d)
| where Classification in ("Security Updates", "Critical Updates")
| where Optional == false
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, Classification, UpdateState, Approved) by KBID, Computer, _ResourceId
| where UpdateState == 'Needed' and Approved == true
| summarize dcount(KBID) by Classification, Computer, _ResourceId
```

Comment: You can also find Update query examples in Microsoft Learn:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/query-logs#missing-updates-summary

Answer (score 0):

- When data of 15 days ago is needed, filter of the query should be
  `TimeGenerated < ago(15d)`
- ago(15d) will give the date 15 days before of current date.
- So, when we give `Timegenerated > ago(15d)` as a filter condition, the data from 15 days ago to current day will be displayed.

I tried to repro with sample table *Covid19_map2* in Azure data explorer. This table has *LastRefreshed* column which is of datetime type. ago() function is applied to this *LastRefreshed* column and output is captured with both cases, *lastRefreshed >ago(15d)* and *lastRefreshed <ago(15d)*.

**lastRefreshed >ago(15d):**

There are no data which got refreshed within 15 days. So there are no rows to display here.
[image]

**lastRefreshed < ago(15d):**

Data which are older than 15 days are displayed
[image]

Refer Microsoft document on [ago](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/agofunction#example) function.